# How do I assign the J1939 standard to a message in a Cantools DBC file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, can-bus, j1939

So i made a python script which can convert a DBC in an Excel and back using the library cantools. Turning the DBC-file into an Excel is no problem, but if i want to create a DBC out of the Excel-file and i assign the J1939 standard to a message, it won't show up in the DBC-file. Instead it only shows CAN extended.

I gave the message with the J1939 standard the attribute `protocol="j1939"` and save the DBC-file with `dumpfile(db, "__.dbc")`. Does anyone know if there is a special setting how i have to save the DBC-file, or if it is possible at all with cantools?

Here a short code example:

```
signal1 = cantools.db.can.Signal(name="signal1", start=1, length=8,
                                 is_signed=True, scale=1, offset=0, unit=None, spn=1586)

frame1 = cantools.db.can.Message(name="Msg1", frame_id=0x16fd3b09, protocol="j1939",
                                 is_extended_frame=True, length=8, signals=[signal1],
                                 cycle_time=50, senders=["A"])

db_cantools = cantools.db.can.Database(messages=[frame1])

cantools.db.dump_file(db_cantools, "test_db.dbc")
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbnM9.png) of the DBC file in Vector CANdb (ID-Format is CAN Extended and not J1939).

For a different DBC file (which contains J1939 messages) i found with

```
db.dbc.attributes
```

a dict of attributes in my database:

```
OrderedDict([('ProtocolType', attribute('ProtocolType', J1939)),...)
```

I don't know if that would be the key, to create this attribute, but I also don't know how i do that. Also in the attributes of the messages i find `j1939` but same problem (don't know how to create them).

Edit: I tried to create a J1939 template DBC file and added the messages there. It works, but messages which use the ID-Format CAN Standard or CAN Extended also turn into the ID-Format J1939.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality of the [documentation](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/) is unfortunately quite poor.

But looking into it, you will find that [`Database`](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cantools.database.can.Database) can take `dbc_specifics` as kwarg, which in turn should be of type [`DBCSpecifics`](https://github.com/cantools/cantools/blob/e196e6ef2fde79cdcaedd0b030fd1905f6023bc3/cantools/database/can/formats/dbc_specifics.py#L6).

In order to set the Database Protocol to J1939, you should create a key `ProtocolType` in `_attribute_definitions` with value of type [`AttributeDefinition`](https://github.com/cantools/cantools/blob/e196e6ef2fde79cdcaedd0b030fd1905f6023bc3/cantools/database/can/attribute_definition.py#L1C7-L1C26).

I don't know if there is an easier way in the API to reach the same result (this one is extremely verbose), but the following will work:

```py
import cantools.database as candb

dbc_spec = candb.can.formats.dbc_specifics.DbcSpecifics(
    attribute_definitions = {
        "ProtocolType": candb.can.attribute_definition.AttributeDefinition(
                            name = "ProtocolType",
                            default_value = 'J1939',
                            type_name = 'STRING'
                        )
    }
)

signal1 = candb.can.Signal(name="signal1", start=0, length=8,
                                 is_signed=True, unit=None, spn=1586)

frame1 = candb.can.Message(name="Msg1", frame_id=0x16fd3b09, protocol="j1939",
                                 is_extended_frame=True, length=8, signals=[signal1],
                                 cycle_time=50, senders=["A"])

db_cantools = candb.can.Database(messages=[frame1], dbc_specifics=dbc_spec)

candb.dump_file(db_cantools, "test_db.dbc")
```

Note that the current version of `Signal` doesn't seem to take `scale` and `offset` as kwarg but rather a [`conversion`](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cantools.database.conversion.BaseConversion) object.

Edit: you can set the protocol of messages individually with the attribute `VFrameFormat`. This should be first added to the attribute definitions of your dbc file. Then as attribute for the desired messages:

```
import cantools.database as candb

vframe_format = candb.can.attribute_definition.AttributeDefinition(
                            name = "VFrameFormat",
                            default_value = 3, # 0: CAN Standard; 1: CAN Extended; 3: J1939
                            type_name = 'INT',
                            kind='BO_'
                        )

dbc_spec = candb.can.formats.dbc_specifics.DbcSpecifics(
    attribute_definitions = {
        "ProtocolType": candb.can.attribute_definition.AttributeDefinition(
                            name = "ProtocolType",
                            default_value = 'J1939',
                            type_name = 'STRING'
                        ),
        'VFrameFormat': vframe_format
    }
)

signal1 = candb.can.Signal(name="signal1", start=0, length=8,
                                 is_signed=True, unit=None, spn=1586)


msg_spec_ext = candb.can.formats.dbc_specifics.DbcSpecifics(
    attributes = {'VFrameFormat': candb.can.attribute.Attribute(
                            value = 1,  # 0: CAN Standard; 1: CAN Extended; 3: J1939
                            definition = vframe_format
                        )}
)

frame1 = candb.can.Message(name="Msg1", frame_id=0x16fd3b09, protocol="j1939",
                                 is_extended_frame=True, length=8, signals=[signal1],
                                 cycle_time=50, senders=["A"], dbc_specifics=msg_spec_ext)

db_cantools = candb.can.Database(messages=[frame1], dbc_specifics=dbc_spec)

candb.dump_file(db_cantools, "test_db.dbc")
```

If you edit a DBC File with Vector CANdb++, you will see that VFrameFormat is an ENUM with the following values:

- 0: StandardCAN
- 1: ExtendedCAN
- 3: J1939PG
- 14: StandardCAN_FD
- 15: ExtendedCAN_FD

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tranbi! I tried it and it works, but if i want to import other messages (for example an Extended message without J1939) it turns it also into a J1939 message. CAN Standard still works. Do you have any idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: Thanks again @Tranbi. It works but i receive an error in the dbc file for CAN extended or  CAN standard messages: `Value of VFrameFormat attribute is below the minimum value` but i think it is not such a big deal. For J1939 messages everthing is fine.